# Optimization of $f(x,y)$ parametrizing the costraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, parametrization

I'm having problems understanding how parametrizing to optimize a two-variable function works.  I have to optimize $$f(x,y) = x^2+y^2 + \frac{3}{2}x+1$$ with the costraint $4x^2+y^2-1=0$ .  I tried to do firstly with Lagrange multiplier, and I found these points: $$\left(\pm\frac{1}{2},0\right), \left(\frac{1}{4},\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$
But if I try parametrizing the function, for example, $f(x,\pm\sqrt{1-4x^2})$ I don't get all the points I need. Why this happens? 
I need to parametrize using $f\left( y,\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{2}\right)$ too. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have  the function:
$$f(x,y) = \left(x+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + y^2 + \frac{7}{16}$$
This is a (imaginary?) *circle* with centre $C(-\frac{3}{4}, 0)$. The value of $f(x,y)$ at $P(x,y)$ depends on distance of $P$ from $C$ ($d^2 + 7/16$, where $d$ is distance of $P$ from $C$).

The other equation is an *ellipse*:

$$\frac{x^2}{1/4} + y^2 = 1$$

Thus you have to find such point $P$ on ellipse whose distance from $C$ is maximum.

**For solving**: Using your method, we have:

$$y^2 = 1-4x^2$$

Substitute in original equation and call this $g(x)$:

$$g(x) = 2-3x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x$$

$g(x)$ is maximum at $x = \frac{1}{4}$. This is easily verified from $g'(x)$.

Thus you get two points where $f(x,y)$ is maximum : $(\frac{1}{4}, \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you just desribed my problem: for Weierstrass I know that there is a maximum and a minimum, but I can only find a maximum substituting that equatiion! Writing $x^2=\frac{1}{4}(1-y^2)$ I get a minimum, in $y = 0$. But why is that, geometrically? Why do I need to parametrize in two differents way to find two different results?

Comment: @L. Repetti You don't need to parametrize again! Note that $g(x)$ first increases then decreases. So to find the minimum, you need to check end points of interval of definition, that is when $y^2 = 1-4x^2 $ is defined. So for this, we get $x \in [\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$. You get two points, at $\frac{-1}{2}, 0$ fn has minima. Remember that to find absolute minima/maxima you must check end points of interval!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: plug in $$y^2=1-4x^2$$ in your function, then it containes only the variable $x$

Comment: I already tried to do that, but it doesn't give me all the points that I have with Lagrange multiplier, as I wrote. Plugging $y^2=1-4x^2$ is equal to $f(x,\pm\sqrt{1-4x^2})$